# Change the color of a category of an outlook email in python

Tags: python, outlook, categories, win32com

I am working on a python project for outlook. The goal is to analyze the content of emails and then put a category on it. To do that, I use the **win32com** library and here is the following piece of code that I use:

```
self.message.Categories = "My category" 
self.message.Save()
```

I'm implementing my own class but if you want, here is an other exemple :

```
    for folder in root_folder.Folders:  # parcours tous les dossiers à partir de l'email choisi

    if folder.Name == directory:
        messages = folder.Items

        for message in messages:  # parcours tous les messages dans le dossier choisi
            if message.Class == 43:  # verify if mail = mail and not an invitation

                
                # Récupération des informations du mail
                receiver = message.To
                cc = message.Cc
                subject = message.Subject
                body = message.Body
                message.Categories = "my category"

                # Message
                print("\n _______________________________________________________________________")
                print("|############################## MESSAGE", countMsg, "##############################|")
                print("|_______________________________________________________________________|")
                print("EXPEDITEUR :", sender)
                print("OBJET :", subject, "\n")
                countMsg += 1

                
                # Catégorisation du message
                if totalLinks <= 0:
                    message.Categories = "Good email"
                    message.Save()
                else:
                    message.Categories = "bad email"
                    message.Save()
```

As you can see, I manage to create a category and assign it to the email but I can't find how to change the color.

This is my class :

Also, I can't add multiple categories to an email. I tried :

```
self.message.Categories = "first, second"
```

And it doesn't work.

If anyone has the solution, I'm a taker !
Thank you in advance !

Comment: Could you provide more details? What library do you use? Are you implementing your own class? And if so could you add it to your question? It's not clear from your question what are you using and where exactly is the issue.

Comment: @Nerxis I updated my post, can you tell me if it's more clear please?

Comment: It's much better. Adding initialization of `self.message` would help as well (to see how do you create message object). But I'm not sure if I can help, I have no experience with `win32com` lib.

Comment: In fact, I get the mail object given by the library to create another one, create by myself in order to be able to use my own methods on it